# Firestore Bundle: Usage of namedQuery necessary?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

**Question**

Using Firestore Bundle, is the data genuinly merged with the local cache?

Or does it exist in parallel under the name given in `namedQuery`?

I would like to avoid using `namedQuery`, yet using a bundle to preload an entire (but small) collection. I want to run queries against that cached collection.

The documentation speaks only about named queries:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles

**Creating Bundle**

```js
const stories = await db.collection('stories')
  .get();


const bundleBuffer = db.bundle("super-duper-bundle")
  .add("stories", stories)
  .build();
```

**Are these two code blocks equivalent after the client loaded the bundle?**

```js
await db.loadBundle(resp.body);

const query = await db.namedQuery('stories');

const result = await query
  .get(GetOptions(source:Source.cache));
```

```js
await db.loadBundle(resp.body);

const query = db.collection('stories');

const result = await query
  .get(GetOptions(source:Source.cache));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be *yes*, the Bundle data is merged with the local Firestore cache.

The code below queries the local Firestore cache successfully.

An official confirmation would have been nice, I assume it is working reliably.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.disableNetwork();

await db.loadBundle(resp.body);

const result = await db.collection('stories').get();
```